# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named notebook

Tags: python, xcode, macos

```
$python3  -m notebook
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named notebook
```

Since the last Xcode (Xcode 12) update I've been getting this error. I'm sure that jupyter is installed. On MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

jupyter is looking in the wrong `bin`.

Try

`python3 -m ipykernel install --user`

(I just spent a few hours trying to figure out the same problem! My Xcode upgraded and jupyter broke. I found a similar error which lead me to this solution here:
https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1824)